# Firebase - Check efficiently username taken

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I developed a small function that checks if the username entered by registering guest is available or not. Nonetheless, the function checks this locally on the device using the iteration and if condition. I am thinking this may become a performance bottleneck in future when there are thousands of users in that list (the list is updated every time a new user is created successfully). Is there a way I can do this more efficiently on the backend side?

Here is the function that works now:

```
func checkUsernameTaken(completion: (result: NSError) -> Void)
    {
        let errorFound:NSError = NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: nil)

        dbReference.child("usernamesTaken").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot!) -> Void in
            if(snapshot != nil )
            {
                for rest in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot]  {
                    if(rest.value as? String == self.usernameTxtField.text!){
                        self.isUsernameTaken = true
                    }else{
                        self.isUsernameTaken = false
                    }
                }
                completion(result:errorFound)
            }else{
                self.isUsernameTaken = false
                completion(result:errorFound)
            }
        })
    }
```

The data structure in Firebase is this:

[image: the alpha numeric is supposedly the UID and the username is admin]

This list will grow as said earlier but for now it is short for testing purposes only.

Thanks in advance

**Update:**

```
 func usernameValidation(completion: (result: NSError) -> Void)
    {
        let errorFound:NSError = NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: nil)

        dbReference.child("usernamesTaken").queryEqualToValue(self.usernameTxtField.text!).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot!) -> Void in

            print(snapshot.childrenCount)
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing the search yourself, let Firebase execute a query. [`FIRDatabaseQuery`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/retrieve-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) allows you to order and filter children by key or value. In your case you can use `queryEqualToValue` to find children of `usernamesTaken` that match `usernameTxtField.text`.

Comment: I am not sure how the above would be used given my key is always changing (because it is a uid). Any examples that could help illustrate your point?

Comment: Sorry I don't use Swift, so I can't really debug your code. But that is the relevant feature.

Comment: Got it to work (in terms of checking) using the above but got some other issues am ironing out.