# Retrieving data with Firebase database in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app I have a simple user base that looks like this:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is to simply fetch this list once, to check wether a username is valid when a new user signs up with a new username.
The thing is that the only ways I found to retrieve data utilize some sort of observer methods, which are not good for me.

The logic I'm trying to achieve (with the retrieving method that doesn't work) :

```
// When user tries to sign up with a new username

let username = nicknameField.text?.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())    

self.usersRef.observeEventType(.Value) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
    let dict = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
    for val in dict.allValues {
        if username == val as! String {
            // Present alert
            return
        }
    }
}   

self.usersRef.child(username).setValue(username) { (error, dbRef) in
    if error == nil {
        // Continue
    }
}
```

How can I simply just fetch the list of users once?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would want to use `ObserveSingleEventOfType`. Chech this link : `https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/retrieve-data#read_data_once`

Comment: Use "observeSingleEventOfType" instead of "observeEventType"

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38334284/213156

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the `observeEventType` method to `observeSignleEventOfType`.
I have also updated my code to make it work (regardless):

```
self.usersRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
let dict = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
for val in dict.allValues {
    if username == val as! String {
        // Present alert
        return
    }
    else {
        self.usersRef.child(username).setValue(username) { (error, dbRef) in
        if error == nil {
            // Continue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're probably not going to want to do it like that. More than likely your structure will change and user1 may have children: user_name, user_bday etc. You would be better off iterating over the snapshot with *for child in snapshot.children*, and then inside that for loop capture data from each child.