# Firebase - Check if Username is taken failing

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to check if the username entered in my app matches any username in my Firebase Database and if so, show a label and disable the continue segue/button.

Instead I get a constant error:

```
  signal SIGABRT (lldb) // for app delegate
```

Here is my code: 
    @IBAction func checkUsernameEntered(_ sender: UITextField) {

```
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: "DATABASE_URL")

    ref.child("users")

        .queryOrdered(byChild: "kid/username")

        .queryEqual(toValue: chooseUsernameTextField.text)

        .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            if !snapshot.exists(){

                print("The username entered has not been previously registered. Tap 'Next' to proceed.")
                self.bottomNextButtonThree.isEnabled = true
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: { self.uhOhWarningLabel.alpha = 0 }, completion: nil)

            }

            else

            {

                print("The entered username has been previously registered. Re-enter to proceed.")
                self.bottomNextButtonThree.isEnabled = false
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: { self.uhOhWarningLabel.alpha = 1.0 }, completion: nil)
            }

        })
```

and here is my database structure on firebase

[image of database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnsZh.png)

any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: I'm sure if you can query like this with the slash in queryOrdered. Try `ref.child("users/kid").queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryEqual(toValue: chooseUsernameTextField.text)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38334284/firebase-check-efficiently-username-taken?rq=1

Comment: i queried it differently but im still getting a error from xcode :( on sigABRT for appDelegate

Comment: weird. you're sure it's because of the query? if you remove it, everything is ok?

Comment: where/when are you calling this function? make sure you have called `FIRApp.configure()` in the AppDelegate before trying to access `FIRDatabase.database().reference`

Comment: Yes If I remove everything it goes to the next view controller via segue, but if i implement and try to access the query, it crashes. and I am it calling it three controllers away from the start. `FIRApp.configure()` is called in AppDelegate

Comment: could `chooseUsernameTextField.text` be nil?

Comment: Wait, it's showing a informative error now: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'No Firebase database specified.', reason: 'No Firebase database found for input: `

Comment: Are you sure you need `.reference(fromURL: "DATABASE_URL")`? I usually just use `static let ref: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference()`

Comment: That was the problem! And I didn't have Firebase installed in my Cocoapods as I thought, only the /Core & /Database segments. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where the issue is

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: "DATABASE_URL")
```

So do this instead (just a rough example)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        ref.child("test_key").setValue("test_value")
    }
}
```

Firebase knows it's app path as it's defined in the GoogleService-Info.plist in the DATABASE_URL entry.

That's the file the Firebase website creates when you create new App in the console.

Comment: Hi, this works, but now I face the problem of it not recognizing the username as a duplicate, even with a matching string. Is there an error in my code with the queries? I suspect it be `if !snapshot.exists()`

Comment: @J.G.Homework So what it looks like you are doing it testing if a username exists before the user registers and if it it exists tell them. If that's correct, I would suggest letting Firebase do the work for you. Just call createUserWithEmail:email:password:completion: and if the username exists an error will be thrown in the completion handler (FIRAuthErrorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse ) and you can handle it from there. Does that work?

Comment: I'll use that if all else fails but really, I'm trying to incorporate a signup flow similar to snapchat where the user enters their data one VC at a time and all the data is passed along the segues until eventually you reach the confirmation page and the data is passed to Firebase.

Comment: @J.G.Homework Yeah - totally understood. We went down that path as well but when Firebase made the change that, as soon as you create the user it logs them in and logs the current user out, we decided to keep it simple and on one view.